# How to display only part of a page in a popup/modal using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, drupal, html, modal-dialog

I am a newbie to Jquery and I am using it in a drupal site.
I use jqModal to display a "popup" or "modal" using ajax to load another page from my site:
Let's say something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#dialog').jqm({ajax: '@href',modal:true, trigger: 'a.trigger'});
      $("a.trigger").click(function() {
        $('#dialog').jqmShow();
      });
    });
```

with an html like this :

```
<a href="examples/examplepage.html" class="trigger">View</a>
<div class="jqmWindow" id="dialog">
  <a href="#" class="jqmClose">Close</a>
  Please wait... <img src="inc/busy.gif" alt="loading" />
</div>
```

The problem is that some parts of the examplepage.html (I don't really want to modify it as it's a dynamic page that can be accessed in other ways) don't need to be displayed; for example I don't need the menus on the side etc. into the popup but only the main content of the page.

It seems as I read in posts here that iframe which was apparently a solution is now deprecated. So is it possible somehow to only display a div content or any other manner of telling "just this part of the page" into a popup/modal using jqmodal? or even another jquery plugin?

Thanks,

Comment: Here's what I use which works for me:
http://www.hedindesign.com/blog/drupal-easy-ajax-content-lightbox2-nodes-and-few-hacks

Answer (score 0):

You could modify examplepage so that it accepts a URL parameter which will cause certain elements not to be displayed.

Or, if jqModal provides a way to specify a callback to execute after the AJAX request completes, you could use javascript to remove different parts of the page.  (This method will likely result in the users on slower computers/browsers to temporarily see those parts of the page.)

Comment: Thanks but as you said I can't let the users see those parts of the page on slow computers/connections.

Answer (score 0):

$.load has an option to only load a selected div.

`$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');`

From the [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/load/) page

Answer (score 0):

I dug into the [source for jQModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/jqModal.js) and it looks like it's just using jQuery's `.load` internally. Since you can append a selector to the URL to extract a piece of the page to display, you should be able to simply do this:

```
$('#dialog').jqm({ajax: 'ajax-url #desired-box-selector',modal:true, trigger: 'a.trigger'});
```

The downside is, of course, unless you modify jqModal, you won't be able to use the `@href` shortcut because it likely won't preserve the added selector. Getting around that is pretty straightforward, though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried it and it worked right away. But instead of using the href, I'll need to find another way to detect the right url depending on the trigger link that will be probably displayed dynamically.